# Node.js and Express - Sending JSON object from SoundCloud API to the front-end makes it a string

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, http, express

I have been using an http.get() to make calls to the SounbdCloud API method to receive a JSON object that I would like to pass to the browser. I can confirm that the data I receive is an object, since I the typeof() method I call on the data prints out that it is an object.

```
var getTracks = http.get("http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?q="+query+"&client_id=CLIENT_ID", function(tracks) {
    tracks.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log(typeof(chunk)); // where I determine that I receive an object
        res.send(chunk);
    });
    //console.log(tracks.data);
}).on("error", function(e){
    console.log("Got error: "+e);
});
```

But when I check the data I receive in the AJAX request I make in the browser, I find that the data received has a type of String (again, I know this by calling typeof())

```
$('#search').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();  
  var q = $("#query").val();
  $.ajax({ 
        url: '/search',
        type: 'POST', 
        data: { 
          "query": q
        }, 
        success: function(data){
          alert(typeof(data));
          alert(data);
        }, 
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, err){
          alert(err);
        }
      })
  });
```

I would appreciate the help, since I do not know where the problem is, or whether I am looking for the answer in the wrong places (perhaps it has something to do with my usage of SoundCloud's HTTP API)

Comment: Haven't really read all this, but I will note that there's no such thing as a JSON object; any JSON will by definition be a string.

Comment: Try JSON. parse(data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is a string. I assume you need an Object representing your JSON string.

Simply use the following method.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
```

Another example would be:

```
var jsonStr = '{"name":"joe","age":"22","isRobot":"false"}';
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
jsonObj.name //joe
jsonObj.age // 22
```

Comment: I would think this would be the answer in most cases for other people, so I will approve but. But in my case, I get an "Unexpected end of input" error on the front end when I call JSON.parse(). Is there are a reason why the JSON string is not well formed?

Comment: check if your json string is valid...there are many online json validators.